# How to make English text appear the same size as Japanese text?

Tags: html, css, cjk

My website includes both English and Japanese characters. The problem is that although they are defined in the same class, they look as if they are different sizes in certain environments. For example, it appears fine on my [laptop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DbgB.jpg) in Chrome browser, but on my desktop in Chrome browser and in my [iphone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybQez.jpg) in Safari browser, the English text appears smaller than the Japanese text.

Below is a snippet of my code:

```css
body,
div,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ul,
ol,
li,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
pre,
form,
fieldset,
input,
textarea,
p,
blockquote,
th,
td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

p,
fieldset,
table {
  /*so things don't run into each other*/
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

* {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#container-right {
  width: 490px;
  float: right;
}

p {
  font-family: Libre Baskerville, "Baskerville Old Face", "Hoefler Text", Garamond, "Times New Roman", serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

html {
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -moz-text-size-adjust: none;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: none;
  -o-text-size-adjust: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "html://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ja" lang="ja">
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=shift_jis" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css" media="screen, projection, print" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://st.shinobi.jp/img/services/homepage/commercial.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <div id="container-right">
  
    <p>Brown准教授、</p>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Changing the Japanese characters to a different, Japanese language-specific p style had no affect.
The language of the html file is set to "ja," but changing it to English had no affect as well.

Please help!

Sincerely,
Hanako

Comment: The different machines use different fonts, probably. You can try using the [`font-size-adjust`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size-adjust) property, but I don't know how that will affect scripts as different as those.

Comment: did you have tried to use `em` instead of `px` for the font size?

Comment: I have tested it. its working fine. I think the problem is with font-family. can you check once.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Its due to the `font-family`.... Suggestion is place these 2 words in different `span` and then adjust their `font-size` separately

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

Select a font that supports both English and Japanese text. This way your text will always be the same height for your text. However, English in these fonts may be quite ugly.

**Solution 2**

The following steps is under the assumption that Japanese is your primary language on your page and English is secondary. Reverse the instructions below if the opposite is true.

1. Make sure you load a Japanese and English font into your CSS/HTML. For example, load them from

   1. https://fonts.google.com/
   2. https://fonts.adobe.com/
   3. Your own fonts using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Styling_text/Web_fonts#web_fonts
2. Wrap all of your English text in `<span class="english-text"></span>`.
3. For your overall text, set your font family to your Japanese font.
4. For your `.english-text` class, set your font family to your English font.
5. Manually pick font sizes to match English and Japanese.

**Explanation**

This problem is because the browser cannot find a matching font from your `font-family` property to render Japanese text. On my Windows Chrome computer, Chrome renders the English text as `Garamond` but the Japanese text as `Yu Gothic`.

It seems that when Chrome (and perhaps other browsers as well), despite explicitly specifying `font-size: 14px`, Chrome will choose an appropriate font size for the different font.

To see the rendered font for some text on Chrome,

1. inspect the text (by right-clicking and selecting Inspect in the context menu)
2. Go to the "Computed" styles tab.
3. Scroll to the bottom to see "Rendered Fonts".
   [image: tips on how to find rendered fonts]